# How to create image file from WEBrick form upload

Tags: ruby, webrick

Unsure how FormData can be turned into an actual file. specifically, an image

```
class Post < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
  def do_GET(request, response)
    File.new("1.png") if request.query["image"]
    # request.query["image"] is a FormData object
    # how do I interpret it and turn it into a usable file?
  end
end
```

..later used on server mount

```
server.mount '/post', Post
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [blog post](http://codefutures.com/rubywebrick-file-upload-multipartformdate/):

> ```
> def do_POST(req, res)
>   filedata= req.query["filename"]
>
>   f = File.open("foo.out", "wb")
>   f.syswrite filedata
>   f.close
>
>   puts "Saved file OK"
> end
> ```

Comment: req is not a FormData

Comment: I believe you should use `do_POST` and not `do_GET`

Comment: I've changed to `do_POST` and the result is the same.

Comment: There is no `req.filedata`, you should use the `filedata` variable you already assigned like this: `f.syswrite filedata`

Comment: @DaKaZ - thanks, I've copied it from the post (I fixed the link) - but I believe you are right about the error, so I fixed it too...